# which localhost server is best for Magento ver. 1.9.3.2

Tags: magento-1.9, server-setup, localhost

which localhost server is best for Magento ver. 1.9.3.2..?

Am tried in `xampp` but it slow

Please anyone suggest me...!

Thank You in advance.

Comment: Please try to use this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8432601/wamp-xampp-is-responding-very-slow-over-localhost